# Location of an object in empty space

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, vacuum, relative-motion

Is it correct to assume that if there is only one object in the void (really empty void), then its location (the answer to the question “where” this object is) cannot be established?

You need at least two objects to be able to tell where each one is.

Or is it theoretically possible to specify where an object is in absolute void (in a certain area of void, top, left, etc.)?

Comment: This is not _really_ physics. Kind of more like philosophy I'd say. Perhaps if you could come up with a physics question that depends on making a coordinate system? So I guess my answer, as a physicist, is: "there's no reason to say where just one object is, because there's nothing interesting to be calculated about the behavior or outcome of that object."

Comment: Then it is better to ask this question on the website of philosophy

Comment: Yes, this is physics. It is one version of the fact that space is relative. There is no physical meaning in the location of one object. We are always establishing "location" as the distance between two objects. A choice of the "reference point" or "coordinate zero" does not matter.

Comment: Theoretically, Newton's concept of absolute space could solve this problem? Or even in this hypothetical absolute space there is no physical meaning in the location of one object?

Comment: If there is only one object, who is to establish the position? If there is an observer, then there isn't just one object.

Comment: I don't think this question deserves a down vote, at least for the theme. It hints at important topics in the symmetries of space(time): translation invariance, dilation invariance, absolute rest frames, Mach Principle...etc.

Comment: @ggkhj Newton's absolute space destroys relativity and without that matter and radiation as we know them go out the window. It's not compatible with observations. One can, of course, imagine non-relativistic universes, at least in an ad-hoc way... we just don't seem to be living in one and that seems to be the "natural choice".

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is faulty. If there is a Universe containing only a single object then you cannot specify its location relative to anything else- that is true. You can arbitrarily label its position with any coordinate you like, but that tells you nothing about where the object is in an absolute sense.

When you say you need at least two objects, you are misleading yourself in the following sense. Suppose your two objects are spheres a certain distance d apart. You can say that sphere 1 is d from sphere 2 and vice versa, but that doesn't 'establish' their positions. Indeed, if you connected the two spheres with a rod, like a dumbell, you would now have a single object again. To go further, if you have n particles you still cannot 'establish' their location in any absolute sense- all you can do is specify their positions relative to each other.

Comment: How is it possible to set location in any absolute sense?

Answer (score 2):

To make the question well-defined we need to specify first what is meant by "the void". The usual practice in physics is that anything called "the void" has symmetry with respect to translations in space. Therefore if there is only void plus one object then the question "where is the object located?" has to be asked more carefully. You need to say what kind of information the word "where" is trying to elicit. In all ways of asking such a question that I can think of, the question is meaningless because I can't see what information it can possibly be trying to elicit.

Note, the term "the void" is sometimes used in other ways. For example it might refer to a region of spacetime with no matter, but which could have curvature and thus it might not have symmetry with respect to spatial translations. Or in a philosophical discussion "the void" might be some kind of hypothetical situation where there are not even any of the Standard Model fields in their ground state. We can't say much about this philosophical idea here on a physics site because we don't know how such a "void" is being defined.

So let's return to physics where we have all the ordinary fields, and let's proceed briefly to two objects instead of one.

If there are two objects then we still can't say much about their location, but we can in principle investigate how far apart they are. For example if the void is the one described by the Standard Model then there is a well-defined notion of time and distance via the fact that one can in principle construct atomic clocks etc. by excitation of the void so as to make electrons and protons and photons etc. and then use them to define temporal duration and hence distance too. Having defined distance like this we can then figure out the distance between the two objects if we can agree a definition of simultaneity. If the spacetime is static then this can be done. If it is dynamic then things get more complicated.

Comment: The fact is that usually the answer to the question, where is the object, is to determine its position relative to another object. For example, "we are on Earth" or "my neighbors are above me".
But if there is one object in absolute emptiness, then the question cannot be answered in this way, if I am not mistaken. Or you can build imaginary coordinates.

Hence the question, is it possible to give an answer in this situation, or does it make no sense?

Comment: I agree your comment. If one builds up some abstract coordinates then the only way to locate the origin of coordinates is to say where it is relative to the single object, so then the question "where is the object relative to those coordinates?" is answered by the way the coordinates were defined: it does not yield any new information.

Comment: Is it correct to say that such a lonely object is "nowhere"? Or is its location objectively uncertain (unknown)?

Comment: Unknown by who? There is no one there.

Comment: objectively uncertain

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can define where the singular object is. You can always define a coordinate system.

If you do that, the object is at $P$, and the origin is at $O$.

For obvious reasons, one may choose $P=O$ (see: Copernicus's detractors).

While an empty flat non-oriented universe has a lot of symmetries, the existence of the object breaks translational symmetry and defines a preferred point. Of course, the orientation of the coordinates is arbitrary.

This is not the same as velocity, where at least in Minkowski space, a singular object simply cannot have a velocity. The only thing with which to compare velocity is light, and no matter what, light will always move at $c$ in all directions, so $\vec v=0$ doesn't mean anything.

Part of this difference is that velocity lives in a vector space, while points live in affine spaces.

A final question is, if the object is a point, then there is no scale, so you also have dilation symmetry...which makes your coordinates even more arbitrary. Roger Penrose uses this oddity in his Conformal Cyclic Cosmology.

Comment: I think it is important to point out that everything we know with some certainty about nature points to "relativity" seems to be the source of most, if not all of physics, maybe with exception of the three dimensional background. And while I do not agree with Penrose on a lot of his crazy recent ideas, CCC seems to solve a lot, if not all of the fundamental cosmological questions (about origins, the deep future etc.) while it's fully compatible with ideas about quantum fields. It also completely eliminates the question about our scale. All he needs, really, is the right effective field.